# PayPal Integration with IOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, paypal

How to get created_time and id after payment success?

i can get confirmation only "completedPayment.confirmation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chek this PayPal delegate method

```
func payPalPaymentViewController(_ paymentViewController: PayPalPaymentViewController, didComplete completedPayment: PayPalPayment) 
{
    print("PayPal Payment Success !")
    paymentViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        // send completed confirmaion to your server
        print("Here is your proof of payment:\n\n\(completedPayment.confirmation)\n\nSend this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.")

        let dict = completedPayment.confirmation
        print("dict data is ====%@", dict)

        let paymentResultDic = completedPayment.confirmation as NSDictionary
        let dicResponse: AnyObject? = paymentResultDic.object(forKey: "response") as AnyObject?

        let paycreatetime:String = dicResponse!["create_time"] as! String
        let payauid:String = dicResponse!["id"] as! String
        let paystate:String = dicResponse!["state"] as! String
        let payintent:String = dicResponse!["intent"] as! String

        print("id is  --->%@",payauid)
        print("created  time ---%@",paycreatetime)
        print("paystate is ----->%@",paystate)
        print("payintent is ----->%@",payintent)

    })
}
```